# How can I statelessly identify a page user who is not logged in?

Tags: php, session, jwt, single-page-application, cart

Can I give a session to an unregistered page visitor of a SinglePageApp (Vue SPA)? So that I can save his shopping cart on the server side (Laravel) without him being logged in?  At checkout, the customer must then log in. Can someone please outline how this can be done? My first thought was JWT. But I thought that only works if you log in?

Comment: A session can exist even without being authenticated...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz And the relationship between session and non-logged-in user is done with a token?

Comment: Correct. You start a session _before_ you show a login page. If a user authenticates, you'll just write "he is authenticated" into the session.. but the session exists, no matter if a user is authenticated or not.

Comment: that sounds logical! thank you!

Comment: this "token" is the session id, and the medium nowadays is a cookie. Eg. the session id is stored in a cookie, and the cookie will be sent to the server with each request. `session_start` will do all the magic in the background (picking up an existing session OR create a new one)

Comment: You mean cookie. What does he mean by localStorage?

Comment: LocalStorage is client-side (browser) technique to store data locally (the server does not see anything of this, unless you write JS code to send it to the server)

Comment: The SPA / frontend and the backend are served from different domains. i my understanding, the cookie handling clientside is only possible by javascript. right? then it doesn't matter whether cookie or localstorag, right?. Just to understand.

Comment: Cookie is kind-of mandatory for a server-side session today. Sending it via GET parameter bears the risk of a session-fixation attack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237915/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-lars-stegelitz).

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it immediately... and don't have time actually^^